# TScrollBox won't work when Anchors is set to []

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7

I have a big panel full of controls that I want to keep centered in the middle of the scroll box. On high resolution, the panel is total visible. But if user has a very small resolution (1024x768) he will probably resize my application and the panel will not be fully visible & accessible. This is where I need the scroll bars to appear. The program is as simple as this:

```
UNIT Unit1;

INTERFACE
USES
...

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    ScrollBox1: TScrollBox;
    Button1: TButton;
    Panel1: TPanel;
    procedure Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
  end;

VAR
   Form1: TForm1;

IMPLEMENTATION  {$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
 Panel1.Left:= 9999;    // Try move the panel 'out of view' 
end;

end.
```

Both Button1 and Panel1 are parented in the ScrollBox1.

When I move the Panel out of the screen (Panel1.Left:= 9999) and Panel1.Anchors is set to **[akLeft]**  the scroll bar appears in the ScrollBox1. But if the Panel1.Anchors is set to **[]** the scrollbars won't appear.

How do I make ScrollBox work with a control that has Anchors set to [] ?

Comment: Could be related to this? http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=98555

Comment: BTW, what behavior do you expect to achieve by setting the Anchors to none in this case?

Comment: @kobik - I have a panel that I want to keep centered in the middle of the scroll box. If the user uses a very small resolution (1024x768) he will probably resize the application and the panel will not be fully visible & accessible. This is where I need the scroll bars.

Comment: I see. Your edit does not make any sense now: `TScrollBox won't work when Anchors is set to alNone` b/c you confuse `Align` and `Anchors`. You already got an answer to your initial question. please read it carefully again. this behavior is by design. You will need to handle this yourself. if you need to ask a **new** questions, please do so.

Comment: @kobik-Fixed: I put the title of the question back to []

Answer (score 3):

With the current setup you are using, I dont think its possible, by design, to automatically handle the scrollbars.

You can see the reason in

```
unit Vcl.Forms;
...
procedure TControlScrollBar.CalcAutoRange;
var
  I: Integer;
  NewRange, AlignMargin: Integer;

  procedure ProcessHorz(Control: TControl);
  begin
    if Control.Visible then
      case Control.Align of
        alLeft, alNone:
          if (Control.Align = alLeft) or (Control.Anchors * [akLeft, akRight] = [akLeft]) then
            NewRange := Max(NewRange, Position + Control.Left + Control.Width);
        alRight: Inc(AlignMargin, Control.Width);
      end;
  end;
```

There is only potential update of NewRange when scrollbox  `align` is `alNone`, `alLeft` or `alRight`. 
For `alNone` it depends on the Anchors. So if the Anchors are not set, there will be no update of NewRange.

One solution could be to change `align` of the scrollbox to `alLeft` or `alRight`. Or set at least anchor `akLeft` on scrollbox children controls.

Alternatively I see its possible to set the ScrollBox scrollbars range manually.

Then it could work by f.ex

```
ScrollBox1.HorzScrollBar.Range := Panel1.Left + Panel1.Width;
```

And generalize it to go over all contained controls.

Comment: @kobik thanks for your note, I have updated the answer with your correction.

Comment: Jesus! What's wrong with that implementation? Why they (Embarcadero) will not process alNone?

Comment: @ChristianHolmJørgensen - Hi Christian. I MUST have the Anchors set to 'none' in order to keep the Panel in the middle of the 'screen' (middle of the ScrollBox in this case).

Comment: @ChristianHolmJørgensen - I just tried in my Delphi XE7 and IT ONLY WORKS when the Anchors is set to alLeft. That's definitively a Delphi bug.

Comment: @FrostyFrog, yes I also think its not clear why they have made these limitations, but it is what they have decided at Embarcadero / Idera. Maybe you need to go with the manual approach then.

Comment: I hate the fact that Delphi RTL/VCL code contains no comments at all. A few words to explain this weird decision would have been nice.

Answer (score 0):

I see now that you have added an explanation of the original problem, that you have been trying to solve with no anchors and a scrollbox. I would do it as follows:

Skip the scrollbox and use the built in scrollbars of the form, by setting `TForm.AutoScroll` to `True`. You might also want to set some of the properties of the forms `HorzScrollBar` and `VertScrollBar`. Usually I set `Smooth` and `Tracking`.

Then, let the panel have its `akLeft` and `akTop` anchors set, and instead center it on the form with a simple `OnResize` handler for the form

```
procedure TForm1.FormResize(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if ClientWidth > Panel1.Width then
    Panel1.Left := (ClientWidth - Panel1.Width) div 2;
  if ClientHeight > Panel1.Height then
    Panel1.Top := (ClientHeight - Panel1.Height) div 2;
end;
```

With those two changes the panel is centered in the form on high resolution screens while scrollable on low resolution screens.

Comment: Thanks Tom. Unfortunately, this won't work. The application I posted is the minimal application required to reproduce this Delphi bug. Basically, it is an almost empty application. The real application is much more complex. There are lots of controls anchored and aligned in all kind of combinations. The panel that creates the problem cannot be simply placed on the main form.

Comment: @Frosty Well, you can of course apply the same solution if you put the panel on a ScrollBox. The point is anyway that getting the scrollbars to show you must have the left and top anchors set. Therefore you need to center the panel manually. Or use Christians solution.